# \printnomenclature doesn't work

Tags: nomenclature

I'm using vscode with the LaTeX Workshop extension (plain instalation).

My document looks like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature

\nomenclature{$\delta x$}{variación de $x$}
\nomenclature{$\delta_x$}{incertidumbre de $x$}

\begin{document}
\printnomenclature
\end{document}
```

The file compiles but however it doesn't show the nomenclature in the pdf.

I read that I had to do some other steps when compiling but I don't know exactly what those are and I can't find the file where to add those.

Comment: Did you already try placing the `\nomenclature` commands inside of the document body instead of inside of the preamble?

Comment: @leandriis Yes, and it does nothing

Comment: How did you compile your document? Using PDFLaTeX, then makeindex, then PDFLaTeX again should result in the nomenclature being printed. Maybe you should also add some actual contents to the document, despite of the nomenclature-related commands.

Comment: @leandriis How do you compile like that? To compile I just click the "build latex project" button.

Comment: That depends on the editor. Which one do you currently use?

Comment: @leandriis As I said, visual studio code and the LaTeX Workshop (and I'm using MiKTex)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue and **solved it by changing the latex recipe** used to build the latex document.

After running LaTeX on your source file (e.g., filename.tex), you need to run makeindex to generate the nomenclature list. The command for this is usually:

```
makeindex filename.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o filename.nls
```

This step is crucial. If you skip it, the nomenclature will not be generated. Since you are using LaTeX Workshop in VSCode, you might need to configure the build recipe to include this step.

This can be done by editing your settings.json in VSCode.
You can access settings.json under **Files->Preferences->Settings**

Then go to LaTeX under Extensions and click on "Edit in settings.json" uner the "Latex: Recipes" and "Latex: Tools" settings.

Add the following entry in the `latex-workshop.latex.recipes` array:

```
{
    "name": "pdflatex - makenomenclature - pdflatex x2",
    "tools": [
       "pdflatex",
       "makenomenclature",
       "pdflatex",
        "pdflatex"
    ]
}
```

And the following entry in the `latex-workshop.latex.tools` array:

```
{
    "name": "makenomenclature",
    "command": "makeindex",
    "args": [
        "%DOCFILE%.nlo",
        "-s",
        "nomencl.ist",
        "-o",
        "%DOCFILE%.nls"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Would be better to name it something like `makenomenclature` as `makeindex` has a range of uses, and `nomencl` is typically not the first expectation.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!